# How to know if a user has activated the "bigger font" accessibility option in android?

Tags: android

How can I determine if a user has the "bigger font" option activated in the accessibility page of an android device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **public float fontScale**
>
> Current user preference for the scaling factor for fonts, relative to
>   the base density scaling.

You can get current scale:

```
float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
```

Default value must be 1. You can debug and see the value for "bigger font"'s value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#fontScale

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is indeed one way to get it... My first test returned a 1.3 factor when "bigger font" was activated and 1.0 without it.